# When training regressor ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python Scarlars

Tags: python, pytorch, regression

I'm new to pytorch. What I want to do is convert an image into an numpy array as input of a regression model. So I transfered images into numpy array and then into tensors. Which is the variable x_train.
But then I got an error as below:

```
x_train = torch.FloatTensor(x_train)
ValueError: only one element tensors can be converted to Python scalars
```

The below is the code for training the regressor.

```
def train_scalereg(network):

   #0) prepare data
   f = open('C:/workspace/darknet/data/scale_train.txt','r')

   path = 'C:/workspace/darknet/data/MSCOCO/val2017/class'
   os.chdir(path)
   files = os.listdir(path)


   print("transforming image data...")
   x_train =[]
   for image_name in files : 
       img = Image.open(image_name)

       data = np.array(img)
       imgToTensorTransformer = transforms.ToTensor()
       tensorFromImg = imgToTensorTransformer(data)
       x_train.append(tensorFromImg)


   x_train = torch.FloatTensor(x_train)
   y_train = genfromtxt('C:/workspace/darknet/data/scale_train.txt', delimiter ='\n')#scale

   n_features = 5000


   #1) model
   input_size = n_features
   output_size = 1 
   model = nn.Linear(input_size, output_size)

   #2) loss and optimizer 
   learning_rate = 0.001 
   criterion = nn.MSELoss()
   optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(),lr=learning_rate)

   #3) training loop 
   num_epochs = 2 
   print("training model...")
   for epoch in range(num_epochs): 
       #forward pass and loss 
       y_predicted = model(x_train)
       loss = criterion(y_predicted, y_train)

       #backward pass
       loss.backward()

       #update 
       optimizer.step()

       optimizer.zero_grad()

       if (epoch+1)%10 == 0 : 
          print(f'epoch: {epoch+1} , loss = {loss.item():.4f}') 

   #plot 
   y_predicted = model(x_train).detach().numpy()
   plt.plot(x_train, y_train, "ro")
   plt.plot(x_train, y_predicted,"b")
   plt.show()


   return model
```

Please help me.
Or if there is other way to train a regressor with a input image it would be a pleasure if you would give me advice.

Answer (score 0):

`torch.FloatTensor` can handle conversion of a list of tensors only in the case they contain only one element. For example:

```py
l = [torch.tensor(3.)] * 3  # creates a list with three one-element tensors

torch.FloatTensor(l)  # returns tensor([3., 3., 3.])
```

In your case, yours are not one-element tensors so you must use a different approach, for example `torch.stack`

```py
l = [torch.tensor([3., 4])] * 3

torch.stack(l)  # returns tensor([[3., 4.], [3., 4.], [3., 4.]])
```

In order for this to work, ensure that the tensors in your list have all the same size, for example by using `transforms.Resize`